# the list of sectors that time I click on the tab menu gives an error partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

the list of sectors that time I click on the tab menu gives an error partial view.

**tab menu**

```
<div class="wizard-navigation">
              <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#sektor" data-toggle="tab">Sektör</a>
                </li>
             </ul>
        </div>


<div class="tab-pane" id="sektor">
 @Html.Partial("~/Areas/CRMWeb/Views/Sektor/PartialView/_SektorListesi.cshtml")  
 </div>
```

**_SektorListesi.cshtml**

```
  @model IEnumerable<CRM.Entity.Entities.Sektor>

<div class="card">
 <div class="card-header card-header-text" data-background-color="rose">
    <h4 class="card-title">Sektör Listesi</h4>
</div> 
      <div class="card-content">
      <div class="toolbar">
    </div>
    <div class="material-datatables">
        <table id="datatables" class="table table-striped table-no-bordered 
         table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sektör Adı</th>
                    <th>Tarih</th>
                    <th class="disabled-sorting text-right">İşlemler</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr id="s_@item.sektorid">
                        <td>@item.sektoradi</td>
                        <td>@item.aczaman</td>
                        <td class="text-right"> 
                            <a class="btnEdit btn btn-success" 
                  href="@Url.Action("SektorDuzenle", "Sektor", new { id = 
                          item.sektorid })">
                                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                                <div class="ripple-container"></div>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="btnSil btn btn-danger btn-
               round" onclick="SektorSil(@item.sektorid)">
                                <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                                <div class="ripple-container"></div>
                            </a> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

ERROR > [_SektorList.jpeg](https://image.ibb.co/dLFoOx/Sektor_List.jpg)

Why a controller does not fall when the _sektorlist... I know I need to work on the controller to pull the data from the list of sectors, but how do I do it?

Comment: have you written your controller action which will return this partial view?

Comment: yes I wrote but the controller does not fall when you call this page.........
 public override Result<List<Sektor>> List()
        {
            return result.GetListResult(db.Sektor.Where(x => x.aktif == false).ToList());
        }

Comment: this does not look like your action method

Comment: CONTROLLER >>>>    public ActionResult SektorListesi()
        {
            result.resultList = sektorRep.List();
            return View(result.resultList.ResultProcess);
        }

* The list goes on method of attracting sektorRep

Comment: That's because you don't pass the model to the partial view here: `@Html.Partial("~/Areas/CRMWeb/Views/Sektor/PartialView/_SektorListesi.cshtml")`

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to call `Html.RenderAction` or `Html.Action` and specify there which action and controller to be called which in return will give the partial view back and will be rendered on the main view.

Try the following:

```
@Html.Action("SektorListesi"ControllerName")
```

which will call the controller action and will render the Partial view in the Main View.

and your action should be returning `PartialView`:

```
public ActionResult SektorListesi() 
{ 
  // your code here

   return View("_SektorListesi",result.resultList.ResultProcess); 
}
```

Comment: <div class="tab-pane" id="sektor">
                    @Html.Action("Sektor", "SektorListesi")
     </div>



The controller for path '/CRMWeb/quickDefination/quickDefination' was not found or does not implement IController.  Gives a fault. 

Having another controller would be a problem. I call the sector list from the fast definition controller

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like this:

**View:**

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("SektorListesi"); }
```

**Controller:**

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult SektorListesi() { 
    ...
    result.resultList = sektorRep.List(); 
    return PartialView(result.resultList.ResultProcess); 
}
```

Notice using `RenderAction` html helper and returning `PartialView` in controller action.

Also I think your partial view should be here: `"~/Areas/CRMWeb/Views/Sektor/_SektorListesi.cshtml"`